# Typescript: Indexed subtype access in generic function gives a supertype

Tags: typescript, generics

```
type A = {
    a: {
        // [key: string | number]: { // workaround 2
        [key: string]: {
            aa: string;
        }
    }
};

// type AInstance<T extends A> = T['a'][number]; // workaround 2
type AInstance<T extends A> = T['a'][string];

function foo<T extends A>(obj: T): AInstance<T> | null {
    // const multiObj: T['a'] = obj.a; // workaround 1
    const multiObj = obj.a;
    
    for (const k in multiObj) {
        if (multiObj[k].aa == 'aa') return multiObj[k]; // Type '{ aa: string; }' is not assignable to type 'AInstance<T>'
    }

    return null;
}
```

I'm trying to work with indexed access and index signature on subtype in generic function and getting the error (see code sample). Looks like `multiObj[k]` is of supertype, but why? For the example above i found 2 workarounds, but don't understand them so can't be sure that they will work in other cases.

The question is: What is the right way to index objects like multiObj  as subtype? By "objects like multiObj" i mean any object type defined with index signature including nested ones.

Comment: TypeScript widens generics to their constraint if you index into them with a non-generic key, as described in [ms/TS#33181](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33181). So `multiObj` is seen as being of type `{[key: string]: {aa: string}}` and not `T['a']`. That answers the question as asked, do you agree? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you for comment @jcalz. I edited the question to be more certain. In your explanation i not quite understand what a generic key should look like. Is it `keyof T['a']`?

Comment: Sure, `keyof (T['a'])` should work. The right way to index `multiObj` is to give it the type `T['a']` to start with. And then you'd index it with `keyof` as with all types.  Does that now address the question and I'll write up an answer? Or am I still missing something?

Comment: Unfortunately i still don't understand how the code should look like with `keyof (T['a'])`. The most concise way for me by now is the workaround 2 (indexing with number) in the code sample above. The problem with that workaround is i don't know why it works so not sure that it's safe.

Comment: Use "workaround 1", that's the correct way to proceed, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/N7G6oN). This whole thing is still ms/TS#33181. Indexing with number is not a good way to do it and explaining that seems to be outside the scope of the question.  If there's a particular place you want `keyof T['a']` you appear, could you clarify? What specifically is the difficulty we're having here?

Comment: The problem with workaround 1 appears when we have nested multi objects as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NrEJDw). About `keyof T['a']`. What do you mean? What i wanted to say earlier that i didn't catch the way of using it to solve the problem.

Comment: I can't worry much about use cases not mentioned in the question. If you need to support it, you might want to [edit] that to reflect that, or you might want to leave this alone, and open a new question to deal with the nested case.  How would you like to proceed?

Comment: Corrected the question to be more explicit.